# Can Q-Learning algorithm become overtrained?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

It has been proved that the Q-Learning algorithm converges to the Qs of the optimal policy which are unique. So is it correct to conclude that the Q-Learning algorithm cannot become overtrained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of overtraining in the world where you assume that you have **infinite access to whole data** (which Q-learning assumes). If you do not use "pure" Q-learning, which is state-space based, but instead some approximators like Deep Q-learning, this can overtrain heavily. Lack of this properpty comes from unrealistic assumptions, which are usually not met (unless your problem is extremely simple/small).

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response. I get it now